# Qt 5.0.2 Memory leak on simple qWebView

Tags: c++, ajax, qt, memory-leaks

I have a problem with a memory leak happening while having a QWebView opened on Qt 5.0.2.
The only thing I do is I open a QWebWindow with a simple local webpage. The script calls the server by doing an ajax request and repeats the action indefinitely. There is no data saved in cache, localStorage or sessionStorage.
The problem is though that the application takes too much memory even after an hour of running. (over 300Mb).

I'm not sure if this is a qt-related problem or a javascript-related problem.

Here's the code I use:

```
#include <QWebFrame>
#include <QWebElementCollection>
#include <QNetworkDiskCache>
#include <QDesktopWidget>
#include <QWebHistory>

#include "mainwindow.h"

MainWin::MainWin(QWidget * parent) : QWebView(parent)
{

    m_network = new QNetworkAccessManager(this);
    m_cache = new QNetworkDiskCache(this);
    m_cache->setCacheDirectory(QStandardPaths::writableLocation(QStandardPaths::CacheLocation) + "/test");
    m_cache->setMaximumCacheSize(0);

    m_network->setCache(m_cache);
    page()->setNetworkAccessManager(m_network);
    page()->settings()->setAttribute(QWebSettings::DeveloperExtrasEnabled, true); // enable inspector
    // local content can access remote urls
    page()->settings()->setAttribute(QWebSettings::LocalContentCanAccessRemoteUrls, true);
    // enable javascript
    page()->settings()->setAttribute(QWebSettings::JavascriptEnabled, true);
    // Plug-ins must be set to be enabled to use plug-ins.
    page()->settings()->setAttribute(QWebSettings::PluginsEnabled,true);
    // Images are automatically loaded in web pages.
    page()->settings()->setAttribute(QWebSettings::AutoLoadImages,true);

    page()->settings()->setMaximumPagesInCache(0);
    page()->settings()->setObjectCacheCapacities(0,0,0); // causing slight flicker on refresh
    page()->settings()->clearMemoryCaches();
    page()->history()->setMaximumItemCount(0);

    // enable local storage
    page()->settings()->enablePersistentStorage("C:\\data\\");

    // hide the vertical scrollbar
    page()->mainFrame()->setScrollBarPolicy(Qt::Vertical, Qt::ScrollBarAlwaysOff);
    page()->mainFrame()->setScrollBarPolicy(Qt::Horizontal, Qt::ScrollBarAlwaysOff);



    // Signal is emitted before frame loads any web content:
    QObject::connect(page()->mainFrame(), SIGNAL(javaScriptWindowObjectCleared()),
                     this, SLOT(addJSObject()));

    setUrl(startURL);

    initEffects();

}

void MainWin::addJSObject() {

}

/*
 * EFFECTS
 */
void MainWin::initEffects() {
    resize(500, 300);
    move(0, 0); // left top corner
}

void MainWin::resize(int width, int height) {
    setGeometry(QRect(this->x(), this->y() - (height - this->height()), width, height));
}
```

the HTML:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Details</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./js/connection.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

    <div>page loaded: <span id="times">0</span> times</div>
</body>
</html>
```

and the Javascript:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    var counter = 0;
    var refreshData;

    refreshData = function() {
        counter++;

        var jData = '{"test":"test"}';

        var request = $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "http://qt.digia.com/",
            dataType: "json",
            data: { jsonData: jData },
            timeout: 15000,  // 15 secs
            complete: function(response) {
                console.log(response);
                delete response;
                $('#times').html(counter);
                // no need to hide the window, usual behavior
                refreshDataTimeout = setTimeout(refreshData, 1000);
            }
        });

        request.onreadystatechange = null;
        request.abort = null;
        request = null;
        delete request;

    }

    refreshData();

});
```

Comment: are you using some tool to detect leak?

Answer (score 0):

I reproduced your problem. And the reason for growing memory is that you use `setTimeout( func, 1000 )` in your javascript.
This greatly increases memory.

I used the following codes and your problem got fixed.

```
setTimeout((function (self) { return function () {

    counter++;

    $.ajax(...);

}; })(this), 1000);
```

Good luck.

Comment: didn't help. If I leave the app running for some time the memory still leaks.

Answer (score 0):

The function writableLocation seems to leak memory.  The Windows version calls 'sHGetKnownFolderPath' which leaks.